# Loop sum find and multiple

Tags: python, json

I tried to figure out how to do that without success. Hope you guys can understand why I'm trying to figure.

I have this data

```
names = "name: almog quantity: 1 status: none name: avraham quantity: 6 status: none name: asaf quantity: 12 status: none name: yossi quantity: 2 status: none name: mishel quantity: 3 status: none"

values_li={'almog':'1.11','asaf':'2.33','yossi':'3.21','avraham':'4.16','mishel':'12.91'}

for k,v in values_li.items():
        if k in names:
                amount = float(v)


print(amount)
```

Now here I have the total amount of each string... But how do I multiple each string for his next quantity string? for example:
almog is 1.11 and his quantity is 1 so
1.11 * 1.....
avraham is 4.16 and his quantity is 6 so
4.16 * 6.....
and so on, and get the sum of all this values.

Thank you, I hope you understand.

*Edit ---

Thanks for all the help but now it gets more complicated...

in the beginning, I had this code

```
names = "name: almog grams: 9 id:141 quantity: 1 status: none name: avraham grams: 3 id:146 quantity: 6 status: none name: asaf grams: 1 id:1241 quantity: 12 status: none name: yossi grams: 2 id:2141 quantity: 2 status: none name: mishel grams: 6 id:1641 quantity: 3 status: none"

values_li={'bar':'47.2','loren':'11.12','yossi':'3.21','avraham':'4.16','mishel':'12.91'}
for k,v in values_li.items():
    if k in names:
        amounts = float(v)
```

So it will only sum the amount if it finds one of the values_li in the names string. No, I don't have any idea how I can do that with the new code you created that find the quantity of each one and multiply it.

Basically, I want to multiply the values in quantity only if its one of the values in the values_li list and then sum it all to one var...

Any ideas on how it can be done?

Comment: You will have to parse the `names` string for those values, maybe a good regular expression could help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to extract the names and quantities from the `names` string:

```
>>> re.findall(r"name: (\w+) quantity: (\d+)", names)
[('almog', '1'),
 ('avraham', '6'),
 ('asaf', '12'),
 ('yossi', '2'),
 ('mishel', '3')]
```

Use a dict comprehension to map names to quantities, and then use another dict comprehension to multiply those with the values to get the results:

```
>>> quantities = {name: float(quant) for name, quant in re.findall(r"name: (\w+) quantity: (\d+)", names)}
>>> {name: float(values_li[name]) * quantities[name] for name in values_li}
{'asaf': 27.96,
 'almog': 1.11,
 'yossi': 6.42,
 'avraham': 24.96,
 'mishel': 38.730000000000004}
```

This is assuming that the `names` string is always formatted in this way, and that both the `names` string and the `values_li` dict contain the same names. (If the latter is not the case, you can use `... for name in values_li if name in quantities}`.)

For your more complex example, use this regex: `r"name: (\w+).*? quantity: (\d+)"`. The `.*?` will match a minimum number of characters between the two fields. This will allow for other attributes between `name` and `quantity`, but it still assumes that `name` is first.

Comment: Hey thanks! This is awesome way to do that.
I have now different issue that's can't be done by this code above.

    names = "name: almog grams: 9 id:141 quantity: 1 status: none name: avraham grams: 3 id:146 quantity: 6 status: none name: asaf grams: 1 id:1241 quantity: 12 status: none name: yossi grams: 2 id:2141 quantity: 2 status: none name: mishel grams: 6 id:1641 quantity: 3 status: none"

This var contains inconsistancy, how do I overcome that and get the same results?

Comment: Awesome it is working, Now there is a way to sum only the float values into 1 var?

Comment: @אסףמזון Sure, just do `sum(result.values())`, assuming `result` is the dict mapping names to floats.

Comment: @אסףמזון Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. Don't the two edits I made to my answer and the comment above already cover those? If not, please provide some desired example output for your example.

Comment: Hey, so when a string from values_li isn't found on names it will break the code.
http://prntscr.com/ltkbth

I want if it is not found the string move on, exactly like the for loop I created (see edit)

Comment: @אסףמזון That's what I added that `... for name in values_li if name in quantities}` part for.

Comment: I got it now, Thank you I missed it. You helped me a lot! appreciate that.

Comment: @אסףמזון In this case, please consider accepting the answer to mark the question as being resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` to parse and convert `names` into a name-to-quantity mapping dict, and then use a dict comprehension to produce the name-to-amount mapping that you are looking for:

```
import re
quantities = dict(re.findall(r'\bname: (\S+) quantity: (\d+)', names))
amounts = {k: float(v) * int(quantities[k]) for k, v in values_li.items()}
```

`amounts` becomes:

```
{'almog': 1.11, 'asaf': 27.96, 'yossi': 6.42, 'avraham': 24.96, 'mishel': 38.730000000000004}
```